# bind Dependency Property to Another Dependency Property in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Control Called My_A_Control and it has a property called Subject

```
public class My_A_Control : Control

public static readonly DependencyProperty SubjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
         "Subject", typeof(string), typeof(My_A_Control), new PropertyMetadata(Confirm);
```

and i have another control called My_B_Control that Inside its template, My_A_Control is used

So I want to change the value of the subject in My_A_Control through My_B_Control

I first created a property as follows in My_B_Control

```
public class My_B_Control : Control

public static readonly DependencyProperty SubjectProperty =
           My_A_Control.SubjectProperty.AddOwner(typeof(My_B_Control));

        public string Subject
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(SubjectProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SubjectProperty, value); }
        }
```

And then I connected them as follows

```
public My_B_Control()
{
  var ctl = new My_A_Control
   {
     Subject = Subject
   };
}
```

But this method does not work

update:

```
 <Style TargetType="local:My_B_Control">
                <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:My_B_Control">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Popup Grid.Column="0" VerticalOffset="4" x:Name="PART_Popup" StaysOpen="False"/>
                        </Grid>
...
```

and

```
public My_B_Control()
    {
      var ctl = new My_A_Control
       {
         Subject = Subject
       };
 _popup.Child = ctl;
    }
```

update 2:
this code work

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source = this;
            myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Subject");
            myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(ctl, My_A_Control.SubjectProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: "*Inside its template*" would typically mean to use a TemplateBinding. How does the ControlTemplate look like?

Comment: @Clemens There is a `<Popup` in `My_B_Control` template and I create `My_A_Control ` inside popup with C# code

Comment: Show us the XAML and code please. Or search StackOverflow for ["binding in code"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+binding+in+code).

Comment: @Clemens please see my question again

Comment: And the search results won't help?

Comment: @Clemens I'm a little confused about how to connect another control property to another property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public My_B_Control()
{
     var ctl = new My_A_Control();

     ctl.SetBinding(My_A_Control.SubjectProperty, new Binding
     {
         Path = new PropertyPath("Subject"),
         Source = this
     });

     _popup.Child = ctl;
}
```

Comment: thank you, please see my question, i found a code that work fine but i want to know is it ok or not?

Comment: That's the same. With more Binding properties that you probably don't need. Is the Binding supposed to be TwoWay? If not, don't set it. UdateSourceTrigger is totally  pointless here.

Comment: I want the user to be able to change the value in xaml with hotreload, Do i need a two-way binding?

Comment: I can't tell. It doesn't hurt to set it.